# How to display a JSON from web service in Android List

Tags: android, json

I am trying since yesterday to make my application take some JSON data generated by a PHP file and then display this data in a list view.

**The PHP File** is encoding data using encode method:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Viewed from the **browsers view source** the JSON generated by file.php looks like this:

```
["","CSD1939","CSD1939"]
```

The [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) (A great tool) validates this as a correct JSON format.

When I am trying to use my application to fetch this JSON from the webservice I am fetching it as a String first but I am having trouble passing it to the adapter and making it display correctly.

I only managed until now to create a listview that displays a String Array.

What is the best way to fetch this JSON data and display it in the list.

```
    package com.example.ams;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ViewClasses extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_classes);

        new GetInfo().execute();

        // ==============Functionality Start====================
        // final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    }

    private class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Fetch the JSON from the web and we pass it as a string to
            // the ON POST EXECUTE method
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "file.php?get=XXX");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "Failed to download file");
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Here it should turn it into a JSON and then display it in a list.
            // Gets the list view
            final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            // Converts the String to a JSON array
            System.out.println(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            try {
                System.out.println(result);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                Log.i(ViewClasses.class.getName(), "Number of entries "
                        + jsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i(ViewClasses.class.getName(),
                            jsonObject.getString("text"));

                    // Converts JSON array to Java Array
                    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    // values instead of jsonArray
                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                        int len = jsonArray.length();
                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < len; i1++) {
                            list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
                mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

My **Layout XML file** looks like this

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Running this code I am getting a blank screen.

Any help, pointers, hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: do you have any errors in LogCat?

Comment: See @Pragnani answer below, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just returning `JSONArray` with `Strings`, so you should not create `JSONObject` from it.

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

this will cause `Exception` as `JSONArray` doesn't contain `JSONObjects`.

So parse like this

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
```